# letters "A,a" of ouput of commands executed within backstick are being replacing with empty space, Why?

Tags: bash

Here is snapshot of my shell missing "a" characters in it!! I'm running ubuntu 16.04

[image: snapshot of my shell]

Comment: Please post here the output of command ``echo `pwd` | hexdump -C``

Comment: Does just the command of `pwd` do the same output?

Comment: @smurf here is the output of echo `pwd` | hexdump -C:   00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 66 20  72 68 20 64 2f 64 72 69  |/home/f rh d/dri|
00000010  76 65 0a                                          |ve.|
00000013

Comment: @Terrance no I tested that with ls and it was the same!

Comment: What happens if you use `xterm` and `sh`?

Comment: @KazWolfe it seems that it just runs fine in both!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would happen if your `IFS` variable got an `a` in it. 
Try the following commands:

```
$ echo "$IFS"   # Note: the quotes are important.
                # I guess that the output will be “a”, or something that contains “a”.
$ pwd           # I expect that this will work.

$ echo "`pwd`"  # Again, the quotes are important.
                # I expect that this will also give correct output.
```

`IFS` is the shell’s list of **i**nternal **f**ield **s**eparators. 
Any character that appears in `$IFS` will be treated as if it were a space
when doing word splitting
of unquoted parameter expansions and command substitution.

There’s no good reason for your `IFS` variable to have gotten an `a` in it;
i.e., if that’s what happened, I have no idea why it happened. 
If you start a new command window (i.e., `xterm` or whatever you use)
and the problem goes away,
then it is *probably* localized to your current command window,
and it *probably* will not come back. 
But, if a new command window has the same problem,
then you should search your `~/.*` files
(i.e., `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, etc.)
for a command that says `IFS=something`.

Comment: Yes your are right there was an "a" in my IFS variable. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Huh. TIL about IFS. +10 to you.

Comment: I learned something new today as well.  You got my +10.  Quickly though, to blank out the IFS, would the command then just be `IFS=`?

Comment: `IFS=` will work as a Band-Aid.  It will cause the shell *not* to split unquoted parameter expansions and command substitutions into words, but, OTTOMH, I don’t see why that would be a big problem.  A better Band-Aid is `unset IFS`, which makes `IFS` null with a bullet, and causes the shell to use the default value — which is space, tab, newline.  To restore it to that correct/default value, type`IFS='(space)(Tab)(Enter)'` (and then Enter again, as usual).  Depending on your configuration, you may need to type Ctrl+V before the Tab to get the Tab to be accepted as a plain character. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Everything I’ve said so far applies to any POSIX-compliant shell. There’s a slightly simpler bash-only command: `IFS=$' \t\n'` (and then Enter, as usual). Note that the first **`'`** is preceded by a `$` and followed by a space.